# Error in using numpy mean on ndarray

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I am using numpy.mean to calculate the mean of a numpy array, but I am getting an error (zip argument #2 must support iteration) and a NAN value.

valueList is initially a list containing unicode strings - copied from python:
valueList = {list}[u'273', u'275', u'255', u'250', u'296', u'282', u'259'....]

After converting to floats using a list comprehension, it shows in python like this:
values = {list}[273.0, 275.0, 255.0, 250.0, 296.0, 282.0, 259.0....]

What am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np

# valueList is bult from pulling apart a JSON object containing strings
# Looks like this:
# valueList = {list}[u'273', u'275', u'255', u'250', u'296', u'282', u'259',....]

# Turning all members of the valueList into float objects
valueList = [float(value) for value in valueList]

# valueList now looks like:
# valueList = {list}[273.0, 275.0, 255.0, 250.0, 296.0, 282.0, 259.0,....]

# converting the list into a numpy like array
values = np.asarray(valueList)  
# values = {ndarray}[ 273.  275.  255. ...,  192.  180.  176.]

# taking the log of the passed value - **Works fine!** - but I do get this warning:
# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log, lnValues =  np.log(values)
lnValues =  np.log(values)
# lnValues = {ndarray}[ 5.6094718   5.6167711   5.54126355 ...,  5.25749537  5.19295685  5.170484  ]

# calculating the mean and sd of the lnValues - **Doesnt work!?!**
lnValuesMean = np.mean(lnValues)
# lnValuesMean = {flost64} nan

# and this gives this error:
# zip argument #2 must support iteration
lnValuesSD = np.std(lnValues)
```

EDIT:

First of all, I apologize for adding then removing things - I'm never sure how much info to include, and often fail to include accurate examples/snippets of code.

So, assuming there is a NAN value, I changed the code to include this:

```
# converting the list into a numpy like array
values = np.asarray(valueList)  
# values = {ndarray}[ 273.  275.  255. ...,  192.  180.  176.]

# removing NANs
values  = values[np.logical_not(np.isnan(values))]
```

But that still didn't work, so I assumed there were negative or zero values, so I also added this:

```
# converting the list into a numpy like array
values = np.asarray(valueList)  
# values = {ndarray}[ 273.  275.  255. ...,  192.  180.  176.]

# removing NANs
values  = values[np.logical_not(np.isnan(values))]

# removing possible negative values and zero values
values = values[values>0.0]
```

And it seems that final filtering, removing possible '0' values, is what worked.  There wasn't supposed to be any zero values in my data set, (there were a total of 6 in ~3500), but oh well.

Comment: How are you initializing your valueList in the first place? I've run your code with an initial `valueList = np.arange(1, 10)` and it runs fine.

Comment: @YannickMeeus, valueList is initially a list containing strings.

Comment: Why would np.log work but not np.mean work?

Comment: That's what's confusing me. They're both quite simple operations. The error message makes little sense as well, as it's telling that what you're passing into np.mean isn't iterable.

Comment: it worked for the list befor edition

Comment: @farhawa, what do you mean?

Comment: @traggatmot before you edit the question there was a list, `valueList = ['275', '289', '173', '264']` I tried to run your code with that list and it worked like charm

Comment: I realized that list wasn't representative - I'm starting to see where the error may come from - form some value that a natural log may not work on in the 3000+ values I am transforming.

Comment: You must have a NaN value in your original list of string. This code works fine, with the `valueList` string values you provided above.

Comment: @YannickMeeus: "Why would np.log work but not np.mean work?" Simply. `np.log` is an element-wise operation, so if you encounter one element for which you don't know how to calculate the logarithm, the obviously right thing to do is set `NaN` there.However, when you calculate the mean of a sequence, how do you deal with `NaN`? Use it as zero?surely wrong in most cases. Calculate as if it was a normal number?Then your sum is also `NaN`. Exclude it from observation?surely not the right thing to do for most cases...Since there's is no universally right thing to do, numpy just does the naive thing.

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ: That does make sense, I made the comment in light of the code and values I was running into that snippet of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, assuming there is a NAN value, I changed the code to include this:

```
# converting the list into a numpy like array
values = np.asarray(valueList)  
# values = {ndarray}[ 273.  275.  255. ...,  192.  180.  176.]

# removing NANs
values  = values[np.logical_not(np.isnan(values))]
```

But that still didn't work, so I assumed there were negative or zero values, so I also added this:

```
# converting the list into a numpy like array
values = np.asarray(valueList)  
# values = {ndarray}[ 273.  275.  255. ...,  192.  180.  176.]

# removing NANs
values  = values[np.logical_not(np.isnan(values))]

# removing possible negative values and zero values
values = values[values>0.0]
```

And it seems that final filtering, removing possible '0' values, is what worked. There wasn't supposed to be any zero values in my data set, (there were a total of 6 in ~3500), but oh well.